# Where to get Elasticsearch shield license?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I start kibana, I got the following exception:

```
LicenseExpiredException[license expired for feature [shield]]
```

I checked the document and only found that:

> The first time you start up the node, a 30 days trial license will
>   automatically be created which will enable Shield to be fully
>   operational. Within these 30 days, you will be able to replace the
>   trial license with another one that will be provided to you up on
>   purchase.

Isn't shield a free software? Where Could I purchase the license? I can't find it in the document.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I contacted ElasticSearch to know how I could get a license for a personal use. I just have a single server, and want a simple security realm (3 users : admin, logstash, kibana).

Well, the good point is that they called me back one hour after the form submission.

But, the bad point is that they have no plan for personal usages, they just have (for now) a single bundle with everything included:

- Professional support (ticket, phone)
- License for every software (Marvel, Shield, Watcher)
- Tons of [cool features](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions)

Unfortunately, it fits perfectly for professional usage, because plans are about **1600 $/year/cluster**.

I told the support that having **no plan for developer** was a bad thing, but the only thing she said is "*sorry*".

So I'm heading toward [SearchGuard](http://floragunn.com/searchguard) because it is free.

Comment: today there is available a developer subscription but in the webpage there is no information about pricing

Comment: @RuBiCK You have to contact them to know about pricing.

Comment: @YuvrajGupta I didn't contact with sales, I don't manage licensing terms/pricing ;)

Comment: pricing has changed to a $/node/year model

Comment: When I contacted them for our small company, they said it would be around $80,000 per year. There's no way we would ever pay that. X-Pack has some fantastic stuff, but it's not very startup/small company friendly.

Comment: Since today, Amazon has released a fully open-sourced version of Elasticsearch with a Security (and Alerting) plugin. More info at: https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 10):

You can request for the subscription using the following link:-

> https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions